# Previous incompatible ef core migrations, how to correctly bypass them in a CI/CD system?

Tags: entity-framework, azure-devops, devops, ef-core-2.0, azure-devops-extensions

So I have a `Dev` and a `Staging` environments (Azure DevOps).

The `CD` pipeline generates a migrations script of the `Dev` environment `DB`. 
This latter is executed by `Staging release` pipeline, to put the `Staging` `DB` up to date.

The generated script contains all the migrations (it is not a `--from`, `--to` script).

Although the command generating the migrations script uses the `--idempotent` parameter, to avoid executing migrations that were already brought to the `Staging` `DB`, some queries would still cause errors (when being syntax checked), for instance when they use some table properties that don't exist any more.

Is there any way to completely bypass/NotExecute the already applied migrations ?

I don't want to go with the `--from`, `--to` when generating the migration script, as the CD pipeline(using the `Dev` environment) can't know about what's been applied or not in the `Staging` environment. That would necessit writing a complex dedicated Powershell script (not time for it).

Comment: I'm afraid there no such way to achieve apply changed migration if you don't want to use from/to and powershell script. It seems more relevant with EF core instead of azure devops. If you can achieve this locally, you can share it. As normal, if the script can used locally, it can also used in command line task in Azure Devops.

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT Hi Merlin, thanks for your answer, please add your comment as an answer so I can mark it as accepted. Concerning my issue, I will try to write an automated PS code for it. Thx again.

Comment: Got it. Will convert it into answer. Thank you:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my experience, and confirmed with my colleagues, I’m afraid that  if you don’t want to use `from` `to` in the generated migration script or use powershell script to achieve this , there’s no such other method can let you bypass the applied migration then only apply the changed migration script.

—-

In local command line, if there’s some script can achieve this, it would also can be used in Azure Devops. In this issue, if you don’t want to use `from` `to` in EF migration command, powershell script would be the only way can achieve what you want to do.